# Focusing input field with Mousetrap.js - but input field also pastes the hotkey as value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hotkeys, input-field, mousetrap

Have a look at the following example. I have enhanced [the official example here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element) with some Mousetrap functionality. So whenever somebody presses `alt+1`, the first input field will focus, whenever somebody presses `alt+2` the second input field will be focused. It works.

**Problem:**
However, the input field then also takes the value of whatever was pressed as the hotkey (`alt+1` then renders to `¡`, `alt+2` renders to `€` in the input). *But I just want this to be a hotkey*, I don't want it's actual value *in the input field*. How do I do this?

I could clear / delete the input field completely. This would work in the example here, but I don't want to do it since in my final app the state of the input field will need to be preserved, so I cannot just delete it.

Any advice?

```
import React from "react"
import Mousetrap from "mousetrap"

export default class CustomTextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    // create a ref to store the textInput DOM element
    this.textInput = React.createRef()
    this.textInput2 = React.createRef()
    this.focusTextInput = this.focusTextInput.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Mousetrap.bind("alt+1", () => {
      this.focusTextInput(1)
    })

    Mousetrap.bind("alt+2", () => {
      this.focusTextInput(2)
    })
  }

  focusTextInput(id) {
    // Explicitly focus the text input using the raw DOM API
    // Note: we're accessing "current" to get the DOM node
    if (id === 1) {
      this.textInput.current.focus()
    }
    if (id === 2) {
      this.textInput2.current.focus()
    }
  }

  render() {
    // tell React that we want to associate the <input> ref
    // with the `textInput` that we created in the constructor
    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" ref={this.textInput} className="mousetrap" />
        <input type="text" ref={this.textInput2} className="mousetrap" />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried event.preventDefault() ?

```
Mousetrap.bind("alt+1", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
      this.focusTextInput(1);
    })

    Mousetrap.bind("alt+2", () => {
        e.preventDefault();
    this.focusTextInput(2)
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

@Dhananjai Pai solution didn't worked for me in the same case.

I know this is very old question, so I will just leave the solution, that worked for me, just if someone needs it.

```html
<input
    type="text"
    placeholder="Put focus here"
    name="something"
    id="order-code"
    class="form-control barcodeScanner"
>
```

```js
if (typeof Mousetrap !== 'undefined') {
    Mousetrap.bind(['`', '('], function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.barcodeScanner').focus()
    }, 'keyup');
}
```

Adding as third option the 'keyup' event solved the issue with typing inside the input.
Source:
https://craig.is/killing/mice#api.bind

> There is a third argument you can use to specify the type of event to listen for. It can be keypress, keydown or keyup.
>
> It is recommended that you leave this argument out if you are unsure. Mousetrap will look at the keys you are binding and determine whether it should default to keypress or keydown.